# How to change the number of columns for mobile break point

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

For desktop view, I have a 12 column container for image gallery. One image takes 4 columns out of 12 in one row, so 3 pics in one row. Now for mobile, I want one picture displayed in one row. How can I change the number of columns on the breakpoint?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper portfolio" id="portfolio">
<div class="row">
<div class="column column-12">
<section>
<div class="column column-4">
<img src="http://wallpaper.zone/img/2253357.jpg" width="80%"></img>
<p class="trigger_text">My workplace</p>
</div>

<div class="column column-4">
<img src="http://wallpaper.zone/img/2253357.jpg" width="80%"></img>
<p class="trigger_text">My workplace</p>
</div>

<div class="column column-4">
<img src="http://wallpaper.zone/img/2253357.jpg" width="80%"></img>
<p class="trigger_text">My workplace</p>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which grid framework you use?

Comment: Just check the docs of your framework if it isn't a framework then search for mediaqueries

Comment: It's not a framework, I made this grid myself. I know about queries, but is it possible to change my html class with css? Like from column-4 to class="column-12"? I don't think so. Coz that's what I need. I could do that with jquery, but there must be a way with css